# await async - race condition error in ESLint require-atomic-updates

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint, race-condition

The code below is causing a race condition when it is checked with [ESLint](https://eslint.org/):

```
  let match = false

  try {
    match = await something()
  } catch (err) {
    // do something
  }
  if (match === false) {
    // do something
  }
```

What is the better way of writing this block of code?

**EDIT:**

```
  let request = ctx.request.body || {}
  let password = request.password
  let match = false

  try {
    match = await bcrypt.compare(password, 'xxxxx')
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.throw(401, err)
  }
  if (match === false) {
    ctx.throw(401, 'invalid password')
  }

  ctx.body = {
    message: 'logged in ok'
  }
```

Error from ESLint:

> Possible race condition: `ctx.body` might be reassigned based on an
>   outdated value of `ctx.body`  require-atomic-updates

Comment: Could you please add the real code?

Comment: @JonasWilms please see my edit above. thanks

Comment: This looks very much like a false positive. I can't see how [the rule conditions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-atomic-updates#rule-details) apply to your code. If this is your actual code, I'd recommend filing a bug report.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for checking it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise it is a little bit late for this answer but just for any future users coming across this question, to disable this rule, in your `.eslintrc.json` or whichever relevant config you use, just specify:

`"require-atomic-updates": "off"`

Comment: Why you don't stop to use ESLint if you are accepting such solutions? This rule is not a stylistic issue, it's a protentional bug. It's like to disable the alert when some problem occurred.

Comment: Agreed. OP asked how they might write their code differently, not how to scrub clean the error report.

Answer (score 17):

You can safely ignore the warning :)

That ESLint is meant to catch things like this:

```js
 let value = 0;

async function race() {
  value += await Promise.resolve(1);
  console.log(value);
}

race(); race();
```

In this case, `race` memoizes `value` on the stack, `await`s a tick, then writes back to `value`. As other code runs in the meantime, `value` could've been changed, and then the update might be off ... it is not atomic.

In your case however, you read from `ctx.request.body` and write to `ctx.body`, so there is no non atomic update. Also, there is probably no other middleware acccessing the same `ctx` at the same time, so there cant be any concurrent modifications. So in your case it is a false positive, it is even questionable that this in any way positive (it might be a bug in ESLint).

Comment: how can i configure ESLint to ignore this? The error does not make any sense

Comment: @laukok Details in this thread: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11899

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this a bug. Let's assume your code snippet is included in an async function, namely `doRequest`.

As long as the `ctx` variable is defined outside of `doRequest`, the `ctx.body` assignment is in race condition. Because it is not possible to assure that the last value assigned to `ctx.body` belongs to the last call of `doRequest`.

I wrote [a blog post](https://transang.me/promise-based-semaphore/) about this race condition. There are 2 ways to avoid this warning

Method 1: move `ctx` into `doRequest` body, then return the `ctx` value at the end of the function.

Method 2: use [promise-base-semaphore pattern](https://transang.me/promise-based-semaphore/)

```
let ctxPromise
```

whenever you fire a request, do a call `ctxPromise = doRequest()`.

Comment: Good answer, but it’s unclear how applicable it is to solving this problem in context. The code sample here is executing inside a request/response HTTP handler like Koa or Express, and `ctx` is a managed object provided by the framework—it will not be reused or called from another context. In most cases, the assignment expression is syntax sugar, as what’s really happening is the response body is being written to the output buffer as a onetime operation. The Eslint rule in this case is absurdly incompatible with the Koa API.

Comment: @maetl Koa app or connect-middleware developer might see this ESlint rule absurd. However, ESlint also doesn't have enough information to make sure that the Koa app or connect-middleware don't call same middleware *simultaneously* with a **same ctx** parameter. Thus, throwing error in this case totally makes sense. I also face the same problem when writing async connect-middlewares. My suggested solution is 1. bypass the error with comment. 2. change the error to warning level in ESLint setting